# In Geocouch, how can I get all objects by lon/lat coordinates?

Tags: couchdb, geospatial

I.e. all objects that contain this coordinates (for polygons) or cross them (for lines)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can collapse the bounding box you query with to a point.

Comment: Can you elaborate further please.